# Why MemSQL is slower than SQL Server for Select SQL with Substring Operations on Binary Columns

Tags: singlestore

I have a table with two binary columns used to store strings that are 64 bytes long maximum and two integer columns.  This table has 10+ million rows and uses 2GB of memory out 7GB available memory, so there is plenty of available memory left. I also configured MemSQL based on http://docs.memsql.com/latest/setup/best_practices/.

For simple select SQL where binary columns are compared to certain values, MemSQL is about 3 times faster than SQL Server, so we could rule out issues such as configuration or hardware with MemSQL.

For complex SQLs that use

- substring operations in the Select clause and
- substring and length operations in the where clause

MemSQL is about 10 times slower than SQL Server. The measured performance of these SQLs on MemSQL were taken after the first few runs to make sure that the SQL compilation durations were not included.  It looks like MemSQL’s performance issue has to do with how it handles binary columns and substring and string length operations.

1. Has anyone seen similar performance issues with MemSQL? If so, what were the column types and SQL operations?
2. Has anyone seen similar performance issues with MemSQL for substring and length operations on varchar columns?

Thanks.

Michael,

Comment: have you tried using `like` in the where clause?

Comment: what is the type? Is it `BINARY` or `VARBINARY`?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation: go back to rowstore, but with `VARBINARY` instead of `BINARY`, consider putting indexes on the columns or creating persisted columns, and try rewriting your predicate with `like`.
If you paste an example query, I can help you transform it.

The relevant docs are here
dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html
docs.memsql.com/4.0/concepts/computed_columns

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to make general answers to perf questions, but in your case I would try a MemSQL columnstore table as opposed to an in-memory rowstore table. Since you are doing full scans anyway, you'll get the benefit of having the column data stacked up right next to each other.

http://docs.memsql.com/4.0/concepts/columnar/

Comment: I am open to try MemSQL columnstore table, which is disk-backed datastore.  In the meantime, given that MemSQL in-memory rowstore table is 10x times slower than MSSQL, which is significant, for Select SQL with substring and length operations on binary columns, could you check with the MemSQL developers to see if these operations would make a difference on varchar columns ?

Comment: I think using varchar won't help too much.  If you rewrite your where clause to use `like` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html), you might see less allocations and, depending on the exact patterns being matched, we can maybe use an index on your two binary columns.

Comment: Also, if you know ahead of time what substring operations you need to run, you can precompute them using MemSQL's computed column feature.  http://docs.memsql.com/4.0/concepts/computed_columns/.

Comment: I tried columnstore table and the same Select SQL with substring and length operations is actually about 7 times slower than the row store table.  Why does columnstore table  performs much slower than  row store table when it is supposed to perform faster ?